# Matplotlib - Line chart alphabetically sorting x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a line chart in matplotlib with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['j','c','m','i','s'], 'col2':[614,670,700,740,800]})

plt.plot(df['col1'], df['col2'])
plt.show()
```

As you can see, the dataframe is sorted in ascending order according to `col2` column values. However, at the time of plotting, matplotlib orders x-axis values in alphabetical order, so while the first element of the axis should be `j`, with matplotlib's ordering becomes `c`. In the real example, this causes great damage to the visualization and understanding of the graph. So how can I make matplotlib respect the Dataframe order?

Comment: Matplotlib 2.1 indeed sorted the values. This is fixed in matplotlib 2.2 or higher.

Comment: That's right. Put as an answer please!Thanks